# Why is one of my 4 cores running around 14-17% and something on my network active while idling?

Tags: release-loki

Is there a reason why only one of my 4 cores is running around 14-17% while idling? ...and why something on my network is active while idling, even with the browser closed?

Notably, I've also apparently uploaded 1.5mbs?!

I'm using gnome-system-monitor. I'm going to shut down my browser, let the PC idle for 10 minutes, then take a screen shot and share it. Unfortunately I can only post 2 images.

## Screenshots of the PC's Processes

[image]
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Is 0.4 Loki the latest version?!

Answer (score 1):

Your network is probably still active because you are still maintaining a connection with the Internet and therefor still sending and receiving packets

Comment: Miller but the one core?! so perplexing. what the hell is using up so much computing power

Comment: I have no idea, i do know that in windows it's usually the system keeping that computing power reserved for other programs so that the os won't completly stop working when one program is asking for too much computing power.